# Как убрать стили и библиотеки из Head без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Дело в том что я делаю так `<head id='head'>` 
предположим в нём было :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
<script src="javascript/librarie.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/load.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/req.js"></script>
```

мне нужно убрать :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
<script src="javascript/load.js"></script>
```

я делаю в javascript :

```
document.getElementById('head').innerHTML = "<meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Nexus</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/global.css'><script src='javascript/librarie.js'></script><script src='javascript/req.js'></script>"
```

и когда это применяется все стили на долю секунды убираются и выходит экран моргает, тоесть страница не перезагружается но всё становится некрасивым , а мне нужно чтобы пользователь вооьще незамечал данного действия .

Comment: Напишите мне на почту. Здесь не нужно засорять. Ваши задачи требуют решения.

Comment: адрес электронной почты какой ?

Comment: В профиле ))

Comment: @GenchiK, что стоит писать здесь, а не на почту? Как-то вы не вписываетесь в сообщество ХэшКода.

Comment: @Crasher Вы просто не в курсе о чём я. При такой реализации не стоит удалять стили и js / динамически их подгружать. Грузите всё в head, используйте jQuery, либо другие Вам известные библиотеки, с их помощью можно реализовать весь Ваш функционал. Пара сриптов + jQuery не будет давать нагрузку на скорость загрузки страницы. Тем более что после первого запуска всё будет кешировано.

Comment: не понятно что в партфолио .. там нет!

Comment: @GenchiK, при чём тут это? Я спросил: почему бы не писать это здесь, а не отправлять человека в личную переписку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присвоить тегам уникальный идентификатор (id), а именно:

```
<link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
<script id="load" src="javascript/load.js"></script>
```

Валидно и для IE6.

С помощью JQuery:

```
$('#style, #load').remove();
```

JS:

```
function remove(elem) {
  return elem.parentNode ? elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem) : elem;
}
remove(document.getElementById('style'));
remove(document.getElementById('load'));
```

Единственное, что потребуется, так это удалить все обработчики, которые Вы навешали в load.js

P.S. Частенько в различных CMS-ках, где используются множество модулей с JS, приходится прибегать к подобному.

Comment: а можно обойтись без JQuery !?

Comment: @Kirpich643 Читайте внимательнее. Вариант с JS указал после **JS:**